# Why use the following statement using aName = library in c#?

Tags: c#

I was searching a ZigBee library for c# and I found [GBee](https://xbee.codeplex.com/). I took a look to the code and I've found the following statement:

```
using AtCmd = NETMF.OpenSource.XBee.Api.Common.AtCmd;
```

Why is used this statement and what means?
Searching into the code I also found that `AtCmd` is used as a "class" to send standard command e.g.(`AtCmd.RestoreDefaults`,`AtCmd.NetworkReset`)

Comment: Its just a way of aliasing a namespace, you can then use `AtCmd.SomeClass` to refer to `NETMF.OpenSource.XBee.Api.Common.AtCmd.SomeClass`. Its generally used when you have 2 namespaces that contain `SomeClass` and it avoids having to fully qualify the namespace on each when you use them in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This meas, that all `AtCmd` statements in code will become from `NETMF.OpenSource.XBee.Api.Common` namespace. It simply means 'default namespace' for this type.

Probably you have in code two exact names, but deriving from different namespaces.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx):

> This is called a using alias directive